# How to overcome 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower' error?

Tags: python, pandas

I have `DataFrame`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'item1':['AK','CK',None],
'item2':['b','d','e'],'item3':['c','e',np.nan]})
```

I want to convert all values of the column `item1` into lowercase.

I've tried:

```
df['item1'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())
```

That gave me an error :

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

I know why it happened. One from my column value is `None`.

I want to anyhow ignore that value and convert the rest of the values into lowercase.

Is there a way to overcome this?

*P.S: My original `DataFrame` may have any number of values as it is returned by another function. Dropping the row is not a case here as those records are important for me.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More general solution for `None` and `NaN`s values is use `notnull` function, anothe solution is use list comprehension.

Also pandas string functions working very nice with `None` and `NaN`s:

```
df['new1'] = df['item1'].apply(lambda x: x.lower() if pd.notnull(x) else x)

df['new2'] = [x.lower() if pd.notnull(x) else x for x in df['item1']]

df['new3'] = df['item1'].str.lower()
print (df)
   id item1 item2 item3  new1  new2  new3
0   1    AK     b     c    ak    ak    ak
1   2    CK     d     e    ck    ck    ck
2   3  None     e   NaN  None  None  None
```

---

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'item1':['AK',np.nan,None],
'item2':['b','d','e'],'item3':['c','e',np.nan]})
print (df)
   id item1 item2 item3
0   1    AK     b     c
1   2   NaN     d     e
2   3  None     e   NaN

df['new1'] = df['item1'].apply(lambda x: x.lower() if pd.notnull(x) else x)
df['new2'] = [x.lower() if pd.notnull(x) else x for x in df['item1']]
df['new3'] = df['item1'].str.lower()
print (df)
   id item1 item2 item3  new1  new2  new3
0   1    AK     b     c    ak    ak    ak
1   2   NaN     d     e   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   3  None     e   NaN  None  None  None
```

List comprehesnion is faster in big DataFrames if not necessary check missing values:

```
large = pd.Series([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) +
random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
for _ in range(100000)])

In [275]: %timeit [x.lower() if pd.notnull(x) else x for x in large]
73.3 ms ± 4.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [276]: %timeit large.str.lower()
28.2 ms ± 684 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [277]: %timeit [x.lower() for x in large]
14.1 ms ± 784 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 10):

Quite simply:

```
df['item1'].apply(lambda x: x.lower() if x is not None else x)
```

If you want to handle other possible types (ints, floats etc) which don't have a `lower()` method:

```
df['item1'].apply(lambda x: x.lower() if hasattr(x, "lower") and callable(x.lower)  else x)
```

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar you're welcome - but obviously Panda knows how to deal with this in a much simpler (and possibly more efficient) way (sorry, I'm not a Panda user so I posted the obvious 'plain python' solution).

Comment: NP.  Though I'm not using your solution in this case, it might help someone in future and there's one more alternative we learnt  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use the `.str.*` functions, these automatically know to ignore both `None` and nulls (those are included verbatim):

```
>>> df.item1.str.lower()
0      ak
1      ck
2    None
Name: item1, dtype: object
```

There is no need to do any kind of selecting here.

See the [*Working with Text Data* documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html):

> Series and Index are equipped with a set of string processing methods that make it easy to operate on each element of the array. Perhaps most importantly, these methods exclude missing/NA values automatically.

and from the [`Series.str` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.html);

> Vectorized string functions for Series and Index. NAs stay NA unless handled otherwise by a particular method.

Although Jezrael proposes you use a list comprehension, this is a false optimisation. For your extremely small sample series with only 3 values, a list comprehension is indeed faster:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> tests = {}
>>> tests['vectorised .str'] = 's.str.lower()'
>>> tests['list comprehension'] = '[v.lower() if pd.notnull(v) else v for v in s]'
>>> small = pd.Series(['AK', 'CK', None])
>>> for name, test in tests.items():
...     count, totaltime = Timer(test, 'from __main__ import small as s, pd').autorange()
...     print(f'{name:>20}: {totaltime / count * 1000:.5f}ms')
...
     vectorised .str: 0.09495ms
  list comprehension: 0.01051ms
```

That almost-10x speed difference looks impressive, but is not realistic or significant (there is a mere 84 *micro*seconds between those two timings)

As soon as the dataset becomes a little larger (a mere 250 rows), vectorised string operations are already faster:

```
>>> larger = pd.Series([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) +
                        random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
...                     for _ in range(250)])  # 250 2-character uppercase strings
>>> for name, test in tests.items():
...     count, totaltime = Timer(test, 'from __main__ import larger as s, pd').autorange()
...     print(f'{name:>20}: {totaltime / count * 1000:.5f}ms')
...
     vectorised .str: 0.15494ms
  list comprehension: 0.16758ms
```

The ratio of nulls make no difference here; here is a sample timing where half the rows have been set to `None`:

```
>>> larger_1in2 = larger.copy()
>>> large_1in2[np.random.random(large_1in2.shape) < 0.5] = None
>>> for name, test in tests.items():
...     count, totaltime = Timer(test, 'from __main__ import larger_1in2 as s, pd').autorange()
...     print(f'{name:>20}: {totaltime / count * 1000:.5f}ms')
...
     vectorised .str: 0.14170ms
  list comprehension: 0.16098ms
```

With a ratio every 1 out 2 rows a null, the timings have not materially shifted. I tried different ratios *including 100% nulls*, and the speed difference doesn't waver, by 250 rows vectorised operations are faster.

But the difference between vectorised string ops and a list comprehension only gets larger (in favour of vectorised string operations) with larger series:

```
>>> large = pd.Series([random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) +
...                    random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
...                    for _ in range(1000)])
>>> for name, test in tests.items():
...     count, totaltime = Timer(test, 'from __main__ import large as s, pd').autorange()
...     print(f'{name:>20}: {totaltime / count * 1000:.5f}ms')
...
     vectorised .str: 0.28704ms
  list comprehension: 0.56312ms
```

You really are not going to even notice the performance difference on small dataframes < 250 rows, and on large dataframes where performance actually starts to matter, the vectorised method is always going to be faster.

Comment: @jezrael: you added that part later. Your *first* answer was deleted. I was surprised the OP wasn't doing this nor that Bruno didn't mention it.

Comment: @jezrael: these are vectorised though. Can you state some timings or link to a post that shows how these are slow?

Comment: @jezrael: I can indeed see that the list comp is almost 10x the speed. The `.apply()` is the slowest.

Comment: I try test it, main it depends of number of None or `NaN`s, if huge amount of this values `str.lower` should be sfaster in really big DataFrame. In my opinion in real data should be mostly string values, not Nones or NaN, so `list comprehesnion` is faster.

Comment: @jezrael: 'really big' is actually not big at all. Vectorised string ops beat the list comp for 250 rows, for example. The ratio of NAs doesn't matter.